# I can't output cyrillic text on the console (it suddenly stopped working)

Tags: c++, windows, locale, fstream, ifstream

I have been writing code like this to display cyrillic text on the console and it has always worked, but it suddenly stopped working for some reason, I don't understand why. What's the problem?

This is on Visual Studio, Windows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    //SetConsoleCP(1251);
    //SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    ifstream input{ "in_text.txt" };
    if (!input) {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Displaying file contents: " << "\n\n";
    string line{};
    while (getline(input, line))
        cout << line << endl;

    input.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I've previously been using `setlocale`, I've also now tried the windows `SetConsoleCP` nothing is working. This is the output everytime:

```
Displaying file contents:

Р?С?РёР?РчС'
```

Also, if there is a better way to output cyrillic text on the console, please let me know.

Comment: Try `"ru_ru.utf8"` [as the `setLocale` value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=msvc-160)

Comment: It works!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Windows OS sometimes behave strangely and unpredictable when it comes to cyrillic in console

You can try SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

it helped me once(<windows.h> header required)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!